# SET DATEFIRST in FUNCTION

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I want to SET DATEFIRST in my function but it is not allowed.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
```

I can add the code in a SP and call the SP from the function but I am not keen on doing that.

I can SET the DATEFIRST before I call my function but I am not keen on doing that as well.

Any other work around?

**EDIT**

Below is the code I want to use in my FUNCTION to return the total working days of the month. But I cant add this code into the FUNCTION because of my DATEFIRST

```
DECLARE @my int
DECLARE @myDeduct int
DECLARE @day INT
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
DECLARE @TotalDays INT

SET @mydate = GETDATE()

SET @myDeduct = 0
IF (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(DW, @mydate)) % 7 not in (0,1)
SET DateFirst 1 -- Set it monday=1 (value)

--Saturday and Sunday on the first and last day of a month will Deduct 1
IF (DATEPART(weekday,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate))) > 5)
SET @myDeduct = @myDeduct + 1

IF (DATEPART(weekday,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))),DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)))) > 5)
SET @myDeduct = @myDeduct + 1

SET @my = day(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))),DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)))

Set @TotalDays = (select (((@my/7) * 5 + (@my%7)) - @myDeduct))

Select @TotalDays
```

Comment: Perhaps you could rework the logic in your function so you are not dependent on `set datefirst`?

Comment: [What is your real problem, not your proposed solution?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please see above, I added my code in to explain how I want to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My usual workaround is to use "known-good" dates for my comparisons.

Say, for instance, that I need to check that a date is a saturday. Rather than relying on `DATEFIRST` or language settings (for using `DATENAME`), I instead say:

```
DATEPART(weekday,DateToCheck) = DATEPART(weekday,'20120714')
```

I know that 14th July 2012 was a Saturday, so I've performed the check without relying on any external settings.

---

The expression `(DATEPART(weekday,DateToCheck) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7` will always produce the value 0 for Saturday, 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, etc.

So, I'd advise you to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE WorkingDays (
    NormalisedDay int not null,
    DaysInMonth int not null,
    WorkingDays int not null
)
```

Populating this table is a one off exercise. `NormalisedDay` would be the value computed by the expression I've given above.

To compute the `DaysInMonth` given a particular date, you can use the expression:

```
DATEDIFF(day,
      DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,DateToCheck),0),
      DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',DateToCheck),'20010201'))
```

Now all your function has to do is look up the value in the table.

(Of course, all of the rows where `DaysInMonth` is 28 will have 20 as their result. It's only the rows for 29,30 and 31 which need a little work to produce)

Comment: Please see above, I added my code in to explain how I want to use it.

Comment: @Etienne - I've added some useful expressions and a proposed solution.

Comment: +1 for `(DATEPART(weekday,DateToCheck) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7`, invaluable! sure beats comparing the weekday names, anyway :O

Answer (score 15):

Instead of

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
```

You can do

```
SELECT (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7 + 1
```

Comment: This is a good one, nice one liner. Gives you 1 for Monday, 7 for Sunday. Needed this for ISO8601 calculations.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41248745/2997016 for a multi line version if modulo is like abracadabra for you

Comment: @ArieKanarie but the answer you linked, unlike this one, doesn't account for the current value of `@@datefirst`, so it only works if that was such that Sunday is weekday `1`. Maybe you could post another answer that fixes that. :P

Comment: Anyway, +1, though I used a modified version without the subtraction and addition, since I only need the numbers to be consistent, not specific. So `0` is Saturday, `1` is Sunday, etc. This means I (A) can accommodate `datefirst` in a function and (B) without the region-specific, slower kludge of comparing to specific `datename`s instead.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative way is to explicitly specify the first day of week value as parameter and avoid depending on `@@DATEFIRST` setting. You can use the following formula to achieve that in your function:

```
(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST + 6 - @WeekStartDay) % 7 + 1
```

where `@WeekStartDay` is the first day of the week you want for your system (from 1 to 7 which means from Monday to Sunday).

I have wrapped it into below function so we can reuse it easily:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDayInWeek](@InputDateTime DATETIME, @WeekStartDay INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    --Note: @WeekStartDay is number from [1 - 7] which is from Monday to Sunday
    RETURN (DATEPART(dw, @InputDateTime) + @@DATEFIRST + 6 - @WeekStartDay) % 7 + 1 
END
```

Example usage: 
`GetDayInWeek('2019-02-04 00:00:00', 1)`

It is equivalent to following (but independent to DATEFIRST setting):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
DATEPART(dw, '2019-02-04 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need Monday as firstday follow this code snippet

```
declare @MyDate datetime = getdate()
                   select CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,@MyDate) = 1   
                            THEN 7 
                          WHEN DATEPART(DW,@MyDate) <= 7 
                            THEN DATEPART(DW,@MyDate) - 1                            
                     END
```

Comment: IMO this doesn't really the question, as it still depends on the current value of `@@datefirst`. It just 'rotates' the weekdays based on that, so you will only get `1` for Monday if the current `@@datefirst` is Sunday. That may suffice for some readers, but it's not a comprehensive answer like Kvasi's. As another note, isn't the `<= 7` redundant, because there cannot be `> 7` weekdays in a week?

Comment: @underscore_d Yes the `<= 7` could also be a simple `ELSE`. At least until we get 8 days a week ;-)