# Set Datefirst in read.jdbc SparkR

Tags: r, azure-sql-database, databricks, sparkr

I'm querying an `Azure-SQL-database` from `Databricks` using `SparkR`'s [`read.jdbc`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/R/read.jdbc.html) function.

I have no issues sending queries to the database, but, I would like to set the beginning of the week on Sunday using `SET DATEFIRST 7;` and I cannot find a way to do so.

I have read the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489404/set-datefirst-in-function) and I could use some of them as a workaround. However, I would like to know if there is a way to set the `DATEFIRST` from `Databricks` (I don't mind using `python` or `Scala` to do it).

My piece of code looks like:

```
query <- "SET DATEFIRST 7;
(SELECT
DATEPART(yyyy,[calday])  * 100 + DATEPART(WEEK,[calday])  as calyearweek
FROM [dbo].[table]) out"

table <-
  read.jdbc(
    url = jdbcUrl,
    database = jdbcDatabase ,
    tableName = query,
    user = user,
    password = password
  )
```

If I erase `SET DATEFIRST 7;` I get the query results.
If I keep it I receive the following error:

> Error in jdbc : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'

Comment: 7 is the default. You don't need to set it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

7 is the default in SQL Azure as you can confirm with [@@DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. You don't have to set DATEFIRST to 7.

```
SELECT @@DATEFIRST;
```

If you need set different values for DATEFIRST try to set it from inside a stored procedure.

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way to SET DATEFIRST from Databricks because I will have to combine different values (not always 7). I believe the approach is explained in the link I included makes the code more sustainable in the long term, however, I'd like to know if the DATEFIRST can be SET from Databricks  for testing while developing.

Comment: Run the statement from inside a stored procedure.